# How to run the server class in gwt automatically at the time of apache starts

Tags: java, gwt

How to write and implement simple cronjob class in GWT?
It doesn't have any error but I need to know how to run the server class at time of apache starts.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use [ServletContextListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) that will be called on the context initialization single time at time of server starts.

Put your logic inside `contextInitialized()` method.

web.xml

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.x.y.z.AppServletContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Listener

```
public class AppServletContextListener implements ServletContextListener {
     @Override
     public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
         ...
     }

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
      ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for ur reply it is working but in that logic block i cant add my logics if i add my code server doesn't starts please check this cod

Comment: @apanizo May be the logic is written in simple non-serlvet class.

Comment: @user3367780 I don't have any idea about your code written for cron job.

Comment: My bad, I read "it is not"... obviously I should spend more time answering :D.

Comment: ok how to start the non servlet class at the time of apache starts

Comment: @user3367780 `contextInitialized` blocks the application from starting until it yields; so how about spawning a thread for your startup work?

Comment: @user3367780 start a new thread in `contextInitialized()` block.